# Generalised Curry - Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying, function-binding

While reading an [article](https://hackernoon.com/currying-in-js-d9ddc64f162e) on implementation of a generalised curry in Javascript, I stumbled upon this piece of code.

```
function curry(fn) {
  return (...xs) => {
    if (xs.length === 0) {
      throw Error('EMPTY INVOCATION');
    }
    if (xs.length >= fn.length) {
      return fn(...xs);
    }
    return curry(fn.bind(null, ...xs));
  };
}
```

I am unable to grok the part of the explanation which states

> We create a copy of fn that has the first k arguments bound 
>   (partially applied) and pass it to curry as the next fn, with its reduced arity of N - k.

How does the arity of `fn` reduced to N-k in the subsequent calls? A bound function with k arguments should have an arity of k right?

Comment: A bound function returns a function with partially applied arguments, so `f(a, b, c)` becomes `f.bind(null, a).bind(null, b)(c)`

Comment: @elclanrs Now it makes sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: Cute: [Function.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) ; it's been around since "forever", and I've never used/seen it before >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bound function returns a function with partially applied arguments, so `f(a, b, c)` becomes `f.bind(null, a).bind(null, b)(c)`.