# JS recursive function

Tags: javascript

I defined a function `let sum = a => b => b?(a+b):a;`

If I do 
`console.log(sum(1)(2)());` I get the output `3`

But If I try 
`console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)());` I get an error.

Why is that?

Comment: post the error that occurs

Comment: Because  the function that `sum` returns doesn't return a function but a number. `b?(a+b):a` either returns `a+b` or `a`. Neither of these is a function in your example.

Comment: Brause sum is a function and sum() is a function but sum()() is not a function

Comment: Because `sum(1)(2)` returns `3`, the call `sum(1)(2)(3)` is like `3(3)`. Don't do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191104/sum23-and-sum2-3-what-is-the-common-solution-for-both/58191650

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it it should have been `sum(a+b)`. I can't believe I missed that :)

Comment: What would be `sum` without arrow functions? `function(a) { function(b) { function() { if (a) return a; else return a+b;  } }  }` ? Just to understand how that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3));
```

it will throw an error because you are trying to invoke the 3rd function; which you never created (`sum(1)(2)` returns 3, which isn't a function).

Your function is a higher order function of two order. A function that returns another function. So the function call should be twice only; you mustn't call the 3rd function, as you did above.